# Convert date to month day using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a DE with a date column in this format

[image]

I desire to change this in the email to read **23 March** and i am using **FormatDate** but it doesn't work

Below is my code

```
    set @Outagedate = field(@row,"Outage_dates")
    set @Outagedate = formatDate(@Outagedate, "m")
```

I have the values in a table. Below is my html.

```
<td style="text-align:center;">%%=v(@outagedate)=%%</td>
```

When i preview this, the email has blanks for the date column. (below)

[image]

Comment: Hope this might help... https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/ ......also I would first suggest to output and check your 'Outagedate' before formatting, just to check the value is pulled!

Comment: Also I am hoping you are using the LookupRows while pulling your rows [asking as I don't see the code above... if NOT here is an example how to use Lookuprows, Row and Field functions together ....  https://ampscript.guide/lookuporderedrows/

Comment: Yes I am using LookupRows and yes it outputs like for like from the DE before formatting. Yes I did read that article and used the monthday in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

DD/MM/YYYY is an ambiguous date format, which will need to be handled based on your business unit configuration.

Per https://ampscript.guide/dateparse

> The function uses the date format defined in the respective the Business Unit. For example, MM/DD/YYYY when the Business Unit date format is set to English (United States) or DD/MM/YYYY when the Business Unit date format is set to English (United Kingdom). If you attempt to parse a string in an incorrect format based the Business Unit date format, for example 30/12/2020 when the Business Unit date format is set to English (United States), then the function will return a String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error.

For example in my business unit, if I parse a date in MM/DD/YYYY format, it works:

```ampscript
%%[

set @dateString= "03/23/2021"
set @year = datePart(@dateString, "Y")
set @month = datePart(@dateString, "M")
set @monthName = datePart(@dateString, "monthName")
set @day = datePart(@dateString, "D")
set @formatted = format(@dateString, "M")

]%%
<br>dateString: %%=v(@dateString)=%%
<br>year: %%=v(@year)=%%
<br>month: %%=v(@month)=%%
<br>monthName: %%=v(@monthName)=%%
<br>day: %%=v(@day)=%%
<br>formatted: %%=v(@formatted)=%%
```

Outputs this:

```
dateString: 03/23/2021
year: 2021
month: 03
monthName: March
day: 23
formatted: March 23
```

But when I use 23/03/2021, it doesn't:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/9nIb3YO.png]

Comment: My BU date format is set to English(Australia) so the ddmmyyyy i would think is the right format for this setting?

Comment: Try using format() instead of formatDate() -- as in my example

Comment: my datestring is a lookup row = set @Outagedate = field(@row,"Outage_dates") The code works when i define the datestring as "03/23/2021" but not when the datestring is a lookup row

Comment: What do you see when you simply output `@outputDate` without formatting at all?

Comment: I see the date like for like as it is shown in the DE.

Comment: I am going to try and reformat the date to the desired format using a query in the DE.